# Print multiple tabs for an Access Report

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have created a report in Access 2013 which is basically the blank version of the Form.  The form is tabbed, and hence the report is tabbed.  The goal is to have the worker print the blank forms (REPORT) and take it with them onsite.  They would fill them out, and have a data entry clerk enter them into the database.

It has been requested that the Blank Forms(Reports) match the look of the online Form as much as possible.  I am wondering if there is a way to print all tabs of the Report at once.  Right now it only prints one tab at a time?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I created a macro using the OpenReport action, selected my report name, changed the view to print, and repeated this until all my reports were selected.

Hope this helps.